# Should end Session on LEX

Tags: session, amazon-lex

Alexa currently has a param that is shouldEndSession that is very handy when you are in a conversation with a user.

Now using LEX I can`t find a similar feature, the only thing is the session timeout that is not the same.

Have anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the closest feature to Alexa's `shouldEndSession` is Lex's `DialogAction type: 'Close'` .

From [Lex Response Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html):

> Close — Informs Amazon Lex not to expect a response from the user. For example, "Your pizza order has been placed" does not require a response.

Comment: That's works :). But still, I would like to do that as a Client not using the Lambda fulfillment. Do you think there is a way to do this?

Comment: I don't fully understand. By "Client" do you mean the 'user interacting with Lex'? By "Lambda fulfillment" do you mean 'fulfillment by Lambda Function'? Perhaps you could expand on your main question (better yet post a new question) and provide example of what you want to achieve, asking how to use Close dialogAction type to do it.

Comment: That is correct. By The client I mean the client application calling LEX. By Lambda fulfillment the Lambda that we can add to control LEX interactions.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoL Sorry this is a bit late...but did this answer your question? Or do you still have a question about how to use Lex's DialogAction 'close'?